# Normal distribution equality proving

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I proved that for $\xi \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1): \mathbb{E}(\xi)=0$ and $\text{Var}(\xi)=1$. How can I prove the following:

Let $\xi \sim \mathcal{N} (0, 1), a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $b\xi + a \sim \mathcal{N}(a, b^2)$.

Comment: what do you mean with $N(0,1)=0$? The LHS is the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$ and the RHS is the scalar $0$.

Comment: @oliverjones, I made a mistake: it's Eξ = 0 and Dξ=1 that I proved

Comment: Look up transformation of variables in regards to probability densities. You need to show that the transformed random variable $X=b\xi+a$ has a density of the same form as the normal density with mean $a$ and variance $b^2$. You can also prove this by noting that $\xi$ and hence $X$ are members of location-scale families.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to prove this. Here is one using Moment generating functions (MGF). MGF of $X \sim\mathcal{N}(a, b^2)$ (normal with mean$=a$, and variance$=b^2$) is $M_{a,b}(t):=\mathbb{E}(\exp(tX))=\exp\left(at+\frac{b^2t^2}{2}\right)$, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Now MGF of $\xi$ is therefore
$$
M_{0,1} = \exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right).
$$
Thus MGF of $b\xi +a$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}(\exp(t(b\xi +a))) = \exp(ta)\mathbb{E}(\exp(tb\xi))= \exp(ta)\exp\left(\frac{b^2t^2}{2}\right),
$$
which is the MGF of $\mathcal{N}(a, b^2)$. Since MGF uniquely determines a distribution (when exists), therefore $b\xi +a \sim \mathcal{N}(a, b^2)$.

Comment: I haven't learned MGF yet, but thanks for this way of proving

Answer (score -1):

Let $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X \sim N(0,1)$

> $E[bX+a] = bE[X] + E[a] = b\cdot 0 + a$

> $Var[bX+a] = E[(bX+a)^2] - E^2[bX+a] = E[b^2X^2 +2Xa + a^2] - (b\cdot 0 +a)^2] = b^2E[X^2] +2aE[X] + a^2 -a^2 = b^2Var[X] = b^2\cdot 1 $

Set $Y = bX+a$ then

> $P(bX+a \le x) = P(bX \le x-a) = P(X \le \frac{x-a}{b}) $ so $F_Y(y) = F_X(\frac{x-a}{b}) = \Phi(\frac{x-a}{b})$

Find the density from here and you have it.

Comment: This is not correct. You must show that it has normal distribution

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I had hit post prior to being done.